# Does mana cost matter at all for Witch Doctor skills?

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-witch-doctor

I'm about 10 levels into my Witch Doctoring experience.  Thus far I've unlocked about 4 or 5 skills I can use on demand.  Each of these skills requires a certain amount of mana in order to cast.

However, no matter how fast I spam any of these skills, my mana amount seems unaffected.  I can throw jars of angry spiders like they were 12 for a $1 on sale this week (with coupon),  without even making a noticeable dent in my mana.  Even when I cast my more "expensive" summoning or debuff spells, the cooldown is far longer than any mana regeneration time I might incur.  The mana globe fills so fast that sometimes I wonder if it drains at all.

Is there any point to having mana?  Should I be at all concerned about how much I have left or how fast it is regenerating?  Is there some point in the game where my mana pool size or regen rate makes any kind of difference?

Comment: Builds with my level 60 Witch Doctor are *severely* limited by Mana concerns.

Comment: @StrixVaria, indeed.  I think at the outset I was thrown by the extremely fast mana regen rate, which seemed *ludicrous* compared to D1/D2 experiences I'd had.  Later in the game though, I've found that it's mostly there to give you near-unlimited access to low level spells, while keeping you from spamming the really powerful ones.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Once you start getting into the stronger spells, you will likely run into mana issues unless you have some sort of strategy for boosting mana.  Otherwise, you'll have to pace yourself.

Acid cloud and Locust Swarm are two spells I use fairly frequently.  If I open with Grasp of the Dead, then cast two Acid Clouds, I won't have enough mana for Locust Swarm.

It really depends on your build, though.  Many pet-centric builds may not really require much in the way of mana assistance, since minions are "fire and forget" abilities.

Answer (score 1):

As with other characters, most of the <kbd>Mouse 1</kbd> [Active skills](http://www.diablowiki.net/Witch_Doctor_skills#Active_Skills) are in effect infinitely castable (except Plague of Toads), as the mana cost is moot due to regeneration.  Beyond those, however, the other spells will significantly dent your Mana pool, especially if you are trying to resummon pets in battle or use channeled spells (again, just like other classes who consume a resource they generate with a primary skill, Spirit, Fury, Hatred)

An example of the latter is the first you might come across; [Firebats](http://www.diablowiki.net/Firebats) will crater your mana.

Answer (score 1):

At your level, you should already have firebats, which will definitely drain your mana pretty quickly if you use it continuously.

But it really depends on your build. Skills like poison dart and spiders are not heavy on mana use, and you probably won't have to worry about it.  Later skills will definitely be constrained from quick use by mana regen rate.